# Streaming a file using Mechanize in ruby

Tags: ruby, mechanize, mechanize-ruby

I'm trying to use Mechanize::Download so I can work with FLV video streams on the fly without buffering the whole video into memory, however Mechanize isn't following the pluggable parser for 'video/flv' and keeps returning a Mechanize::File instead. Is there a way to use Mechanize to return an IO-like stream of a file? The file only needs to be read once so seeking isn't necessary. I need mechanize to submit the right Cookies and referrers to get the file.

```
irb(main):072:0> nn.agent.pluggable_parser
=> #<Mechanize::PluggableParser:0x0000000192eea0 @parsers={"text/html"=>Mechanize::Page, "application/xhtml+xml"=>Mechanize::Page, "application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml"=>Mechanize::Page, "image"=>Mechanize::Image, "text/xml"=>Mechanize::XmlFile, "application/xml"=>Mechanize::XmlFile, "video/flv"=>Mechanize::Download}, @default=Mechanize::Download>
irb(main):073:0> nn.agent.get(vid.video_url).response['content-type']
=> "video/flv"
irb(main):074:0> nn.agent.get(vid.video_url).class
=> Mechanize::File
irb(main):075:0>
```